# Api Rest Angular 7

Tags: javascript, angular, api, angular6, tokens

Tengo datos desde un backend de donde se envia el username y el password, deseo consumir esos datos desde una interfaz Angular donde se escriban estos datos y me responda con un token en caso de ser true sino que me envíe un error que me llegan desde una url.

He mirado ejemplos donde se utiliza un fakeBackend(usuario falso) pero no logro entender en el caso de consumir los datos desde un backend real en la web.
Ejemplo del fakeBackend:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpRequest, HttpResponse, HttpHandler, HttpEvent, HttpInterceptor, 
HTTP_INTERCEPTORS } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable, of, throwError } from 'rxjs';
import { delay, mergeMap, materialize, dematerialize } from 
'rxjs/operators';

@Injectable()
export class FakeBackendInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {

constructor() { }

intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    // array in local storage for registered users
    let users: any[] = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('users')) || [];

    // wrap in delayed observable to simulate server api call
    return of(null).pipe(mergeMap(() => {

        // authenticate
        if (request.url.endsWith('/users/authenticate') && request.method === 'POST') {
            // find if any user matches login credentials
            let filteredUsers = users.filter(user => {
                return user.username === request.body.username && user.password === request.body.password;
            });

            if (filteredUsers.length) {
                // if login details are valid return 200 OK with user details and fake jwt token
                let user = filteredUsers[0];
                let body = {
                    id: user.id,
                    username: user.username,
                    firstName: user.firstName,
                    lastName: user.lastName,
                    token: 'fake-jwt-token'
                };

                return of(new HttpResponse({ status: 200, body: body }));
            } else {
                // else return 400 bad request
                return throwError({ error: { message: 'Username or password is incorrect' } });
            }
        }


    // call materialize and dematerialize to ensure delay even if an error is thrown (https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/issues/648)
    .pipe(materialize())
    .pipe(delay(500))
    .pipe(dematerialize());
}
}

export let fakeBackendProvider = {
// use fake backend in place of Http service for backend-less development
provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS,
useClass: FakeBackendInterceptor,
multi: true
};
```

Comment: pues como puedes ver el fake solo detiene la llamada y genera una respuesta para entregar un json, para un api real solo apagas el fake, y la llamada la realiza directa al api de la url que tu determines. ejemplo puedes usar https://api.github.com/

Comment: Hola Miguel, pasa que apenas empiezo a trabajar con el tema de APIs, detener el fake significa dejar de llamar el archivo y llamar otro?

Comment: no se si en tu aplicacion estes corriendo la aplicacion  para mock: npm run start:mock, cuando elaboraste la aplicacion debiste leer en alguna parte como apagar el mock o dejar de utilizarlo.